# text inside div overflows... but returns to normal only after refresh

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a dynamic div that resizes accordingly to the amount of text. (Which means I can't define the width of the main div)

Problem is, with [my current CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/sdMTJ/4/), this is what's happening at the first load of the page:

[image: div text is cut]

However, when I press <kbd>F5</kbd>, the page automatically resizes itself back to this:

[image: div text is uncut after refresh]

Why is this happening? How do I solve it? I'm stumped on this part and I've even tried advanced CSS functions such as `calc`, etc.

I can't replicate the problem on jsFiddle, but I did provide the code I'm using.

**HTML**

```
<div class="breadcrumbz">
    <ul id="breadcrumbs" class="uppercase">
        <li><a href="http://localhost/adsg">Home</a></li>
        <span>/</span>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/adsg/blog/" title="View all posts in blog" rel="category tag">blog</a></li>
        <span>/</span>
        <li class="single">On the Go.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.breadcrumbz { padding:6px 6px 6px 6px; margin:2% 0 0 4%; position:relative; background-color:#3b3c3e; float:left; }
.breadcrumbz ul { white-space:nowrap; float:left; }
.breadcrumbz ul li { display:inline; }
.breadcrumbz ul li:first-child a { padding:0 4% 0 0; }
.breadcrumbz ul li a { padding:0 4%; }
.breadcrumbz ul li span { padding:0 4%; }
.breadcrumbz ul li:last-child a { padding:0 0 0 4%; }
.breadcrumbz ul li.single { padding:0 0 0 4%; }
```

Comment: please show the relevant parts of your code here, shouldnt have to go to jsfiddle to view it.

Comment: Have you tried clearing browser cache / different browsers? Probably not a solution, but worth a shot. Another idea I got is that div only scales properly once content is already displayed

Comment: clear browser histories and cookies and try again

Comment: You are using invalid html (span cannot be a direct child element of ul)

Comment: @Sumurai8 yeah I noticed that, I already used xec's method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the percentages causing it, the browser doesn't know what the width will be before the content is rendered, and the percentages in the margins of the content are based on the width. (A sort of chicken-and-the-egg problem.)

You also have invalid html (`<span>` is not allowed as children of `<ul>`).

If you change the units from percentages, you won't have this issue.

Sample at http://jsfiddle.net/sdMTJ/5/

---

Sidenote: instead of the invalid spans, you could add separators between the elements using pseudo-elements;

```
li + li:before {
    content: " / ";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sdMTJ/9/

Comment: if anyone needs to know, it was the percentages in padding for the `<a>` tags that caused the browser irregularity. and thanks for your help xec, not to forget the rest that also chipped in. keep it awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the display style of li. Try "inline-block" insted of "inline".

```
.breadcrumbz ul li { display:inline-block; }
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Yg58f/. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Percentages and padding can have this effect on floated items without set width, particularly. For reliability I would sugget you use `em` and not `%`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/sdMTJ/8/

`.breadcrumbz ul li.single { padding:0 0 0 0.625em; }`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
.breadcrumbz ul li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```